# Hr class double border

Tags: css, class

I'm requesting your help with a `.css` `hr` class

I'm trying to figure out how to make a double border like this:

[image: Sample]

Here's what i did:

```
hr.style15 {
    border-top: 4px double black;
}
hr.style15:after {
    content: 'SHIPPING INFO';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    left: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

My questions are:

1) How do I get rid of the `inline-block` below the 2 lines? I've tried by deleting the `inline-block` sentence but it doesn't work.

2) Can I add `font-family` and font size to this?

3) Is it possible to increase the space between the 2 lines without increasing the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a check with this:-

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="title"><span>Shipping info</span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
    h1.title {
        margin-top: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    h1.title:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border-top: solid 1px black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    h1.title span {
       background: #fff;
       padding: 0 20px;
       position: relative;
       z-index: 5;
       margin-left: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: you could make it as runnable example

Answer (score 1):

Basically I believe I'd do it differently. Using both :after and :before for the lines will help you drastically on putting a text on top of it.

So I prepared this CodePen for you. Basically what I did was using an :after and a :before (as I told you before) for the border-lines and after that I added a span with a background-color (in this case white) on top of the border-lines (look at the z-index).

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.double-bar {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
  }

  span {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    left: 40px;
    padding: 0 7.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

You can see a [demo](http://codepen.io/oriolrodri/pen/zKOAWV/) of this.

I hope this helps!